# Perform action when an entity is updated in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to run code when an entity is updated?  For example I have an entity that is updated many places in my code.  I want to be able to update a DateTimeUpdated field any time that entity is updated without changing every function that updates that entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done by overriding the `SaveChanges` method in the DbContext.

Start by introducing a base class or a common interface for your editable entities that you want to track the DateTimeUpdated for:

```
public abstract class EditableEntityBase
{
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated { get; internal set; } 
}
```

Your entities that you want to track this for should extend this class or implement a contract interface that will expose the property.

Then in your DbContext, override the `SaveChanges` method and insert:

```
var updatedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(x => x.Entity)
    .OfType<EditableEntityBase>();
foreach (var entity in updatedEntities)
{
    entity.DateTimeUpdated = DateTime.Now; // or DateTime.UtcNow
}

return base.SaveChanges();
```

You can also include `x.State == EntityState.Added` for new records, though generally I'd rely on a Default at the DB to capture it on insert.